# Optimize wikidata query to reduce time. SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am getting timeout on below query.
Can anyone please help me to optimize it?

```
SELECT ?human ?humanLabel ?alternative ?humanDescription ?birth_date ?image ?occupationLabel ?nationalityLabel ?sex_or_genderLabel ?date_of_death WHERE {
   ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5. 
   ?human wdt:P18 ?image.
   ?human p:P569/psv:P569 ?birth_date_node.
   ?birth_date_node wikibase:timeValue ?birth_date.
   optional {?human wdt:P106 ?occupation.}
   optional {?human wdt:P27 ?nationality.}
   OPTIONAL {?human wdt:P21 ?sex_or_gender.}
   OPTIONAL {?human wdt:P570 ?date_of_death.}
   OPTIONAL {?human skos:altLabel ?alternative.}
   FILTER (year(?birth_date) >= 1981).
   FILTER (year(?birth_date) < 1982).
  
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
      }
}
ORDER BY ?name
```

Comment: your date filter is very inefficient. Use `?human wdt:P569 ?birth_date.
   hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true.
   FILTER("1981-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime <= ?birth_date &&
         ?birth_date < "1982-00-00"^^xsd:dateTime)` which can make use of an index

Comment: the other issue is with the label service, which is more often than not very slow, especially for more complex queries.

Comment: After adding date filter it is still same. It works for year 2000 onward since there are less entries but not for older years. How can I divide it into six months period?

Comment: Do you really need alternative labels in all languages? If not, see https://w.wiki/UhX. Other improvements are also possible.